# MATLAB how to write header in text file

Tags: file, matlab, file-io, header, text-files

How to write a text header in text file? for example in the example below, how to write the header `code salay month` just once?

```
Code Salary Month
12   1000   12
14   1020   11
11   1212   9
```

The code:

```
fid = fopen('analysis1.txt','wt');
for i=1:10
   array = []; % empty the array
   ....
   array = [code salary month];
   format short g;
   fprintf(fid,'%g\t %g\t %g\n',array); % write to file
end
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there any reason for not using simple solution like following?

```
...
fid = fopen('analysis1.txt','wt');
fprintf(fid, '%s\t %s\t %s\n', 'Code','Salary','Month');
for i=1:10
   array = []; % empty the array
...
```

Comment: Or write the header line as you suggest @pepiino, then use dlmwrite to append the table of data in one statement.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it easy to copy and paste

```
fid = fopen('Output.txt','wt');
fprintf(fid, '%s\t %s\t %s\n', 'x','y1','y2');
% have a matrix M(N,3) ready to go
dlmwrite('Output.txt', M,'delimiter', '\t', '-append')
fclose(fid);
```

Jaap

Answer (score -2):

Thanks, 
Here is a script I modified to generate one variable file,

```
fid = fopen('vout.h','wt');
format short g;

fprintf(fid,' /* Header File for the variable vout */  \n\n' );

fprintf(fid,'int vout[ %g ] = { ' ,length(vout));

for i=1:length(vout)

   fprintf(fid,'%g,',vout(i)); % write to file
end
fprintf(fid,'} ; ');

fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Downvoting: Unnecessarily imposes arcane syntax on the output that wasn't asked for, hard to read, inefficient (especially compared to the other answer which has the correct way of doing this), very hard to read (I actually know how to do this, and still couldn't figure out what's going on).

Comment: @Superbest: He evidently interpreted the question as "output a C header file".