# Reading and Writing Header to File using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am reading in a .txt-file using importdata:

```
MC_file = importdata('D:\Simon\Dropbox\SGM\Gigerwald\Results\Multi_SGM_10000.txt');
Data = MC_file.data
Header = MC_file.colheaders
```

which gives me a struct-variable with the header and the data-body:

```
data = 10000x52 double
colheaders = 1x52 cell
```

Now i'd like to change the data, i.e. add some columns to the end of the file and then print the file again with the same header + 5 new columns.

The body can be printed easily using `dlmwrite()`, e.g. like this:

```
dlmwrite('SGM.txt',Data,'precision',8,'delimiter','\t','newline','pc','-append')
```

...but how do I print the header into the file, of which I have a array of cells? I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052062/matlab-how-to-write-header-in-text-file), but since I end up with 57 columns hard-coding is not an option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is attainable using `repmat`. Assuming that your file is tab separated, you can use:

```
NUM_COLS = 57;

A=cellstr(num2str((1:NUM_COLS)'))';
fid=fopen('newfile.txt','w');

fprintf(fid,repmat('%s\t ',[1,NUM_COLS]),A{:});
fclose(fid);
```

The result can be previewed with:

```
sprintf(repmat('%s\t ',[1,NUM_COLS]),A{:})
```